# NEST JSON Serialization Could not create an instance of type NEST.IHit

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, elasticsearch, nest

So what I am trying to do is to build an index of various index models specified as SQL views with ElasticSearch.

What I simply do when indexing is something like:

```
public void IndexAllFoos() 
{
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    using (var db = new Db()) 
    {
        // where IndexModelFoos are an sql view.
        var foos = db.IndexModelFoos.Select(p => p).ToList(); 
        client.IndexMany(foos);
    }
}
```

This works without any problem.

The problem comes when I try to search the index:

```
 var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
 client.Search<IndexModelFoos>.Search(s => 
     s.Query(q => 
         q.Bool(bq => 
             bq.Must(m =>
                 m.QueryString(qs =>
                     qs.Query("bar")
                 )
             )
         )
     )
 );
```

When I do this I get the following exception:

```
{"A different value already has the Id '1'."}
```

So after some searching I did this:

```
internal class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
            var contract = base.ResolveContract(type);
            contract.IsReference = false;
            return contract;
    }
}

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(...);
settings.SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier(x =>
{
    x.ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver();
});
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

which solved the whole "A different value already has the Id '1'" problem.
However, after doing this I got the following exception when trying to search with the same query:

```
{"Could not create an instance of type Nest.IHit`1[Database.IndexModelFoo]. 
Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.
Path 'hits.hits[0]._index', line 1, position 133."}
```

For this error I can't find any solution. Thus asking here. Anyone got any ideas on how to resolve this problem?

Notice:
The IndexModelFoo is of type EntityObject and generated by Entity Framework

Comment: Given that type `IndexModelFoo` is a class generated by / for Entity Framework, it's maybe not the best candidate for ES indexing. If you were to *project* your instances of `IndexModelFoo` into a POCO dedicated to ES indexing, which has only the properties you want to index, and *no* functionality (i.e. a data transfer object), you wouldn't *solve* these errors, but you would *avoid* them.